# jquery each adding custom method over iteration

Tags: jquery, object, methods, each

I have a collection of checkboxs and I want to create a custom method for them depending on which class they have.

```
var checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]");
    checkboxs.each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("class1")){
            $(this).method1 = function(){
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                return $(this);
            }
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("class2")){
            $(this).method1 = function(){
                $(this).parents("tr").next().hide();
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                return $(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Then if, I want to do this:

```
checkboxs.each(function(){
        $(this).method1();
    });
```

It tells me that there's no method1 method. Why doesn't that  work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could write an common function extending jquery prototype.

```
$.fn.method1 = function(){
    if(!this.is(':checkbox')) return this; //If it is called on a non check box just do nothing
    if(!this.is('.class1, .class2')) return this; //if this is not of targetted classes return

    if(this.is('.class2')){ //if class2 hide the next of its closest tr which comes up in its parent hierarchy.
        this.closest('tr').next().hide();  //using closest assuming you want to check only its immediate tr in its parent hierarchy
    }
    this.prop("checked", false); //uncheck it if it is class 1 or 2
    return this;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLfH5/)**

- This way you can extend this functionality to any other elements.
- You can customize by setting options, (ex: to specify classes callbacks etc)

With the below you can avoid iteration at source:

Method:

```
$.fn.method1 = function () {
    this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.is(':checkbox')) return true;
        if (!$this.is('.class1, .class2')) return true;
        if ($this.is('.class2')) {
            $this.next().css('color', 'red');
        }
        $this.prop("checked", false);
    });
    return this;
}
```

Usage:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").method1();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8cER/)**

Comment: Nice, this is a nicely elegant (and jQuery) way of solving the actual problem.

Comment: @cincodenada Thanks. Probably can be improved much better though... But guess would be more reusable if OP is interested in extending the functionality...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$(this)` creates a new jQuery object with the `this` variable. This is done each time you call `$(this)` therefor adding a method to `$(this)` in one place will not make the method last in subsequent calls to `$(this)`.

This jsFiddle shows the problem http://jsfiddle.net/92cub/1/

EDIT: I that the function could differ for each element, I've changed the given code to use the `data` function in jQuery instead. Also you were doing `$(this)` repeatedly so I removed that. The call `$(this)` is quite heavy to do over and over again.

**Instead you could do something likes this:**

```
var checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]");
    checkboxs.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);  

      if($this.hasClass("class1")){
           $this.data("func", function (){
                $this.removeAttr("checked");
                return $this;
            });
        }
        if($this.hasClass("class2")){
            $this.data("func", function(){
                $this.parents("tr").next().hide();
                $this.removeAttr("checked");
                return $this;
            });
        }
    });
```

**To call the function use:**

```
checkboxs.each(function(){
    $(this).data("func").apply();      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign properties like that to a jQuery object, as it's just a wrapper around the element and will be re-created each time.

If you want to attach attributes to an element, use the [`data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  I'm not sure if this works for functions, but it's worth a shot.

In your case though, I suspect we have a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I would simply check the class of the object in the callback.

An example of what this might look like:

```
method1 = function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("class2")) {
        $(this).parents("tr").next().hide();
    }
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    return $(this);
}

checkboxs.each(function(){
    method1();
});
```

Depending on your use case, it may also work to just call each() on selections, which might look something like just running this instead of the last bit of code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox].class1').each(function(){
    $(this).method1 = function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        return $(this);
    }
});
$('input[type=checkbox].class2').each(function(){
    $(this).method1 = function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").next().hide();
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        return $(this);
    }
});
```

Without some actual code and context, we can't really tell you how best to do what you want.

Comment: Very nice point about the `XY` problem. OP should probably adhere to your answer more than mine.